# Showing html page inside a php page by echo the html page contents

Tags: php

I have a html page like this:

```
<div>
 some html tags here
</div>
<script> some javascript for rendering calender</script>
<link> some css </link>
```

I have a calender in this html page which is rendering by some javascript. I want to display this page content inside a php page.I have tried this:

```
  include(location of html page);
```

I have include it in the middle of my php page but it render calender in the top of the php page which I do not want.
I also tried this:

```
echo file_get_contents(location of my html page);
```

It shows html page content in the right place where I added this line but calender is not rendering.
I need to render calender and html page content in right place. Any suggestion will be helpful for me.

Comment: did u include the HTML file along with the <head> and the <body> tags?

Comment: Hi Kevin Paladin, No i did not include Html and body tag.I have tried with html and body tag also.it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, a simple html page:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Page title</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="your-style-file.css" media="all" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="your-javascript-file.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="div-tag">A div tag</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="another-javascript-file.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

You can load external html file via javascript (or [jquery load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)). like this:

```
 $('#div-tag').load('external-file.html');
```

Or via php, like this:

```
 $external-html = file_get_contents('external-file.html');
 print $external-html;
```

Check your javascript, maybe you must place it on page bottom after calender code.

Comment: Thnaks QQQ for your answer.In my scenario your first solution is not applicable and the second one i have tried already.it did not works.